# How to hide and show a CATextLayers without animation

Tags: ios, swift

I have multiple `CATextLayers` that are being added to an `AVVideoComposition`. I want to hide and show them at certain points in time in the video. Therefore I have the following code:

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)

let startVisible = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
startVisible.fromValue = 0.0
startVisible.toValue = 1.0
startVisible.beginTime = startTime
startVisible.duration = 0
startVisible.fillMode = .forwards
startVisible.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
textLayer.add(startVisible, forKey: "startAnimation")
CATransaction.commit()

CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
let endVisible = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:"opacity")
endVisible.fromValue = 1.0
endVisible.toValue = 0.0
endVisible.beginTime = endTime
endVisible.duration = 0
endVisible.fillMode = .forwards
endVisible.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
textLayer.add(endVisible, forKey: "endAnimation")

CATransaction.commit()
```

This works, however, it does animate the fade between opacity levels despite `CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)`. How can I change this so that the change in opacity is instant and not animated?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to set the duration to a tiny amount e.g. 0.001, rather than 0. The `CATransaction` functions aren't needed.